# react-simple-maps Renders map upside down

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to copy what is done in this example (except making it in one file rather than 2):

https://codesandbox.io/s/map-chart-with-tooltip-xwijz?from-embed

**Issue:**

I'm getting everything to work, except the map renders upside down.

**I've tried:**

- using a projection (d3-geo.geoEqualEarth) in the hopes that the map
  will receive its orientation from the projection
- changing projectionConfig scale and rotation in the hopes that any of those might change how the map is rendered
- modifying topojson file found at the link and changing its "transform" property

  - (Note: I encountered a separate issue which I felt wasn't as relevant since this issue should be resolved without having to modify the original topojson file. Passing a filepath to  resulted in a XHTTPRequest)
- removing non-essential components such as ZoomableGroup
- modifying the css

**My Code:**

Map.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactTooltip from "react-tooltip";
import {
    ZoomableGroup,
    ComposableMap,
    Geographies,
    Geography
} from "react-simple-maps";

const geoUrl = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/zcreativelabs/react-simple-maps/master/topojson-maps/world-50m.json";


const MapChart = React.memo(({ setTooltipContent }) => {
    return (
        <ComposableMap>
            <ZoomableGroup>
                <a data-tip="">
                    <Geographies geography={geoUrl}>
                        {geographies => 
                            geographies.map(geo => (
                                <Geography
                                    key={geo.rsmKey}
                                    geography={geo}
                                    onMouseEnter={() => {
                                        const {
                                            NAME, POP_EST
                                        } = geo.properties;
                                        setTooltipContent(
                                            `${NAME} - ${POP_EST}`
                                        );
                                    }}
                                    onMouseLeave={() => {
                                        setTooltipContent("");
                                    }}
                                    style={{
                                        default: {
                                            fill: "#D6D6DA",
                                            outline: "none"
                                        },
                                        hover: {
                                            fill: "#F53",
                                            outline: "none"
                                        },
                                        pressed: {
                                            fill: "#E42",
                                            outline: "none"
                                        }
                                    }}
                                />
                            ))
                        }
                    </Geographies>
                </a>
            </ZoomableGroup>
        </ComposableMap>
    )
})

function Map() {
    const [content, setContent] = useState("");
    return (
        <div>
            <MapChart setTooltipContent={setContent} />
            <ReactTooltip>
                <span>{content}</span>
            </ReactTooltip>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Map;
```

**Edit:** It might be important to know that I modifying projectionConfig in ComposableMap doesn't modify the map, so changing scale doesn't scale up the map

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `react-simple-maps` version from example,its "1.0.0-beta.0"

```
"dependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "16.8.6",
    "react-scripts": "3.0.1",
    "react-simple-maps": "1.0.0-beta.0",//here
   "react-tooltip": "latest"
  },
```

by default npm install latest version,you should force npm to install betta vesion

```
npm install react-simple-maps@1.0.0-beta.0
```

and also change

```
 { geographies  =>
              geographies.map(geo => (
```

to

```
 {({ geographies }) =>
              geographies.map(geo => (
```

Comment: Thanks! That ended up working for me. Regarding your second suggestion, my modification was necessary with the latest version because otherwise it would complain that the geographies attribute doesn't exist, but your version works in the beta version of react-simple-maps